# How do I use checkboxGroupinput's values in R with shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am using Shiny with R to create an interactive graph. I have a checkboxGroupinput which asks the user to select a few options.

How do I then actually use these checked options in my server function to do some code?

For example, if we have two boxes that can be checked, "Five" and "Four"
then I want these values to use in my code, e.g.

```
server <- function(input, output) 
{

le <- len(input$numbers)
if ("five" %in% input$numbers) 
{
    a <- "text"
}


}
```

The important thing is that I can treat the input$numbers as a vector of strings containing "Five" and "Four", and I can access its length and so on.

How do I do this?

EDIT: note: above code obviously does not work,

Comment: Please a provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap them in a reactive statement such as an `observe` or `reactive`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("numbers","Select value 5",choices = 1:10),
  textOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  value <- reactive({
    a <- F
    if (any(input$numbers %in% 5)){
      a <- T
    }
    a
  })
  output$text <- renderText({value()})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Ok, but what is the format of input$numbers? Is it a vector like c( 3, 4, 5)?